# Is it possible to add a constraint to check every inserted object into a JSON array using Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, constraints, jsonb

I am trying to figure out how to add a constraint to my table that contains a JSON object in Postgres. I would like that constraint to make sure a jpg will have a non null md5 property.

I have tried to check the subarray but I cannot get it to work on an array. I can test the property if use the dereferencing arrow operator (table->'jpg'->0 ? 'md5'). I have tried to use the jsonb_array_elements() function as well but it is not allowed inside a constraint statement.

For instance:

```
{
    jpg: [
        {
            md5: "some md5",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I would use this:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT md5_is_defined CHECK(table->'jpg'->0 ? 'md5')
```

But I don't want to check just the first inserted element

I would like to know if there is some trick to use jsonb_array_elements in this check statement. And yes I realize I should normalize my data. I tried to do this but it became a monstrosity to write the statements for.

Comment: "*I tried to do this but it became a monstrosity to write the statements for*" So you prefer to write monstrosities that unnest and re-aggregate the array each time you need to change a single item in that array? Why is the md5 in an array anyways? Do you expect to have more than one md5 value for each jpg?

Comment: This was just an arbitrary example. I am not using this data structure. I am using one that has many optional fields (30+?) and many more other fields and in my limited experience it became a huge headache. I would rather do this yes since the db size will be small and performance are not critical. It's a hobby project mostly for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are extremely cumbersome to deal with in SQL as they basically violate anything that SQL does. Checking every element in an array for the presence of something is typically a strong indication that an array was the wrong choice to begin with.

With Postgres 12 this is extremely easy to do:

```
alter table the_table 
    add constraint md5_is_defined 
    check (jsonb_path_exists(the_column, '$.jpg[*].md5'));
```

For older versions, the only thing I can think of is to create a function that checks the presence and then use that function in the check constraint:

```
create or replace function check_md5(p_input jsonb)
  returns boolean
as
$$
select exists (select *
               from jsonb_array_elements(p_input -> 'jpg') as t(e) 
               where e ? 'md5');
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
alter table the_table 
    add constraint md5_is_defined 
    check (check_md5(the_column));
```

---

**Edit**

To check if a specific key contains a non-empty array you can use something like this:

```
alter table the_table
    add constraint non_empty_array
    check (jsonb_path_exists(the_column, '$.event ? (@.teams.type() == "array" && @.teams.size() > 0)'));
```

The check for `@.teams.type() == "array"` is necessary because a simple `{"teams": "yes"}` also returns a non-zero value for `size()`

Comment: I upgraded to 12. Is it possible to check array length? I can do top level arrays no problem but I am having trouble figuring out a sub array.
`jsonb_array_length(event->'teams') > 0` works fine for instance and I've tried using json path query but it says its not allowed in a check statement.

Comment: @kmm3: see may edit (as a side note for future questions: it is typically not considered good practice to extend the scope of the question once you have an answer)